# Can't close columntoggler after poll updates

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

First of all I'd like to thank Stack overflow for being such awesome and answering almost everything we need.But again I've stuck to something and need **Help**.My problem is that my columntoggler does not have a close button on the top right(So, when p:poll updates the datatable,toggle does not close and everytime I've to refresh the whole page :(  ).So,Do we need jquery to add that or something that I'm doing wrong.Please suggest me.Thank you

```
<h:form rendered="#{bean.value!=null}"  >

    <p:dataTable id="tab" var="var" value="#{bean.value}" >

                 <f:facet name="header">
                    Header for dataTable
                    <p:commandButton style="float:right" id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns"  icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
                    <p:columnToggler datasource="tab" trigger="toggler">
                     <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onToggle}" />

                        </p:columnToggler>


                 </f:facet>
    <p:column visible="#{bean.list[0]}">
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Start"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{var.startTime}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column visible="#{bean.list[1]}">
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="End"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{var.endTime}" >
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"  />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column visible="#{bean.list[2]}">
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Name"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{var.name}" >

            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

        <p:poll interval="10"  update="tab" />
   </h:form>
```

Comment: Hm, normaly the toggler closes if you click somewhere outside the toggler panel or you click the commandbutton assocciated with the toggler. So the problem can only occure if you have the toggler open an you are waiting for the poll script to execute. I don't think that this is a normal use case. But a simple approach would be to click the commandbutton via javascript like PF('toggler').click();  if the poll event happens. You can use the p:poll attribute oncomplete to do this

Comment: tried adding <p:poll interval="10"  update="tab" oncomplete=" PF('toggler').click()" /> But Not working :(

Comment: Maybe try document.getElementById('tab:toggler').click();

Comment: when I tried to add <p:poll interval="10"  update="tab" oncomplete="document.getElementById('tab:toggler').click()" /> Poll stops working .

Comment: As I've found on [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml) there is a cross sign at the top-right.IDK why but its not showing on my page.

Comment: This ist the brand new Primefaces 6.0 Release Canidate 1. Seems like in 6.0 ther is an close button

Comment: 6.0 ?Is it already released? All I could find that the dependencies are till 5.3

Comment: I've tried adding 6.0 jar to one of my other projects and found the toggler still do not have cross sign at the top-right.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your columnToggler a name so you can access it using PF('columnToggler') like this:

```
<p:columnToggler widgetVar="columnToggler" datasource="tab" trigger="toggler"/>
```

You can hide the columnToggler using PF() and/or with jquery. I found that when the table is updated while the column Toggler is open, there are multiple copies of it so you need to close them all with jquery too.

```
<p:poll inteval="10" update="tab" 
        oncomplete="PF('columnToggler').hide();$('.ui-columntoggler').hide();" />
```

I haven't tried it with poll but I used it with a p:ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** You can close the columnToggler, when the 'toggle event' is triggered, using `PF('widgetVar').hide` using `onstart()/oncomplete()` etc.

```
<p:columnToggler datasource="tab" trigger="toggler" widgetVar="colTogglerWidgetVar">
                 <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onToggle}"  
                  onstart="PF('colTogglerWidgetVar').hide();" />
</p:columnToggler>
```

**Case 2:** You can the columnToggler, even when the table is updated while the toggle event is triggered using `PF().hide` by using `onstart()` event only!! Because when you update the table, a new set of elements are add to page with the same signatures but the columnToggler which is still open to you will be the older one and hence if you try to close the columnTogller using the close button, it won't close. Since the dialog has lost its scope with the current state.

Therefore any other event other than onstart() wont serve the purpose.

```
<p:columnToggler datasource="tab" trigger="toggler" widgetVar="colTogglerWidgetVar">
                 <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onToggle}"   
                 onstart="PF('colTogglerWidgetVar').hide();" update="datatable"/>
</p:columnToggler>
```

If you wish to keep the dialog open,even after you hide the columnToggler, then go for showing the columnToggler again using `PF().show` with `onComplete()` combination

```
<p:columnToggler datasource="tab" trigger="toggler" widgetVar="colTogglerWidgetVar">
                 <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onToggle}"   
                 onstart="PF('colTogglerWidgetVar').hide();" 
                 oncomplete="PF('colTogglerWidgetVar').show();" update="datatable"  />
</p:columnToggler>
```